# PostgreSQL - decimal value to 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm getting this error message

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "g2 ...
```

My SQL code (PostgreSQL)

```
db_connection.execute(f'UPDATE mytable SET g1 = ROUND(CAST(float8 g2 - g3 as numeric), 2))')
```

What I'm looking for is to convert from a string that contains huge decimal points into 2 places.

Sample data after minus g2-g3 is 22.980000000000004. what I want is 22.98

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: I already updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is off. Cast the strings to `numeric` before subtracting:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET g1 = ROUND(CAST (g2 AS numeric) - 
               CAST (g3 AS numeric),
               2
              );
```